Given $n$ people in a room, what is the least amount of questions one has to ask of the type "does A know B" to determine whether a star person exists
Given are $n$ people in a room, some of which know others ($A$ knowing $B$ does not imply $B$ knows $A$). A star person is someone who knows noone else, but whom everybody knows. What is the least amount of questions of the type "Does $A$ know $B$" we have to ask to definitely determine whether a star person exists in the graph?
I was given this problem by a friend and I have made the following progress:
Intuition
Let's keep track of the people who are still 'candidates' to be a star, meaning no answer to a question so far has indicated that they know someone or that someone else doesn't know them. Note that a question of the type "Does $A$ know $B$" if $A$ and $B$ are still candidates at the time of asking will eliminate exactly one of them from the list of candidates (if the answer is yes, then $A$ cannot be a star, otherwise $B$). This shows us that with $n-1$ questions we can eliminate all but one person from the list of candidates. Once this person is left, we have to at some point have definitely asked about their relation to any other in the room. This shows us that with $n-1 + 2(n-1)$ questions we can for sure verify whether a star exists.
Better bound
The above is a weak bound since some of the $n-1$ questions used to eliminate $n-1$ of the candidate-stars can also be a question involving the last candidate. To maximize this number, we might to the following for the first $n-1$ questions:
Imagine the $n$ people like players in a tournament. At first we divide them in pairs (if there are an odd number, leave one aside) and make them "play each other" (i.e. ask whether one knows the other). The 'winner' is the one who is not crossed out of the list of candidates. After every round, all winners (and possibly the odd one if they haven't played) move on to the next. Since our last candidate star stays till the end, they have played roughly $\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil$. So we can manage with no more than $n-1 + 2(n-1) - \lceil \log_2(n) \rceil$ questions.
I have no idea how to prove this number of questions in necessary (seems highly intuitive, but no idea how to do it rigorously)
Also not sure if this is even the best number of questions
Any help will be appreciated. :)

It seems correct. I have a doubt about $\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil$ ; maybe it is $\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor$ ? Did you check with small numbers ? You could also add some details in the process : for example, if $n$ is $2^k+1$, at each step, the number of remaining candidates is an odd number, we have to exclude one candidate when we create pairs. We need to ensure to not exclude someone who was already excluded in previous steps.

To prove the lower bound, you want to show that for every strategy, there exists a way to answer each of its questions with "yes" or "no", in such a way that makes the strategy require at least $3(n - 1) - log_2(n)$ questions. To figure out how to do this, use the intuition you described: given a non-candidate and any other person, we have a clear sensible choice (give the answer that makes the non-candidate into a non-candidate). Given two people who are still candidates there is also a reasonably clear choice: make the answer discard whichever one has the most information known about. ...

The idea in the last sentence is not fully accurate. You don't quite want to do what I described, but something similar. You want to make the notion of "knowledge" only takes into account knowledge gained from questions which actually eliminated a potential candidate.

To determine a star person we need $2(n-1)$ questions even if we have only one candidate。
We need to rule out people until there is only one candidate left. Notice a question removes at most $1$ candidate, so we will need at least $(n-1)$ questions for this part.
Now we need to make the $2(n-1)$ questions and $(n-1)$ questions in the two parts above coincide. Here we assert that, in the worst case scenario, we cannot achieve a result with better order than the pairwise method proposed in the OP. This is because when there are two candidates left, we hope they have already "won" for the same number of questions, otherwise we will risk wasting some questions. This argument works when we have two candidates each for the two final candidates as above, and so and so forth.
Finally, we have to tackle the most complicated floor and ceiling stuff. We use the pairwise strategy as in the OP, and whenever there are odd candidates, we let one person that has "won" for the greatest number of questions pass free to the next round.
However, in the worst case scenario, at some point we may find that there are an odd number of candidates left, and all people left have passed free for one round, and so and so forth. Then we have to waste one question. The number of these people would be at most $\log_2n$.
And this may happen again and again, giving a correction with order of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}H(\log_2^{i}(n)-\log_2(3))$, where $\log_2^{2}(n)=\log_2(\log_2(n))$, and so on. $H$ is the Heaviside step function.
So the best upper bound I would accept would be $3(n-1) - [\log_2(n)]+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}H(\log_2^{i}(n)-\log_2(3))$. I believe more detailed discussions would be too complex.
